# Joining Multiple Tables in MySQL Using Sean Lahman Database

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I am using Sean Lahman's baseball database trying to return a table of players with counts of AllStar games played, AllStar games started, and total career games. When I enter the below query, I am getting the incorrect numbers in AllStar, Starts, and Games columns.

```
SELECT p.nameFirst AS FirstName, p.nameLast as LastName, COUNT(a.gameNum) as AllStar, count(a.startingPOS) as Starts, sum(e.G_all) as Games
FROM People p
    INNER JOIN AllstarFull a ON p.playerID = a.playerID
    INNER JOIN Appearances e ON p.playerID = e.playerID
GROUP BY p.playerID
ORDER BY 3 desc;
```

Comment: please provide your sample data and expected result.

Comment: Whats the granularity of the Full and Appearance tables? 1 row per player, per game, or something else?

Comment: You typically `GROUP BY` the same columns as you `SELECT`, except those who are arguments to set functions.

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.  Don't assume that strangers on the internet understand what you are trying to do.